# jQuery UI - How to remove gap at each rounded corner of accordions

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have collapsible sections created using jQuery UI Accordion.  When each section is expanded I apply a background image to its header part like this:

[jQuery UI Accordion Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AWDsL/)

If you look closely at the section headers, you will notice a gap at each rounded corner.  Obviously the gaps will disappear if I remove the following CSS (but I'd like to use the image):

```
background: url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/images/ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #DFEFFC;
```

Is there a way to use the image but remove the gaps at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, add a border radius to the element with the background on and match it to the radius of the header.

ie

```
border-top-left-radius: 6px;
border-top-right-radius: 6px;
```

If you really want to go to town

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a {
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header.ui-state-active a {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
```